# Does Azure Maps support Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, azure-maps

We are doing a R&D to select the best possible maps framework which can be used with Angular 2+ (Currently we're using Angular 6). We mainly looked into 2 options which are,

Google Maps
Azure Maps

For google maps, we found out the URL : https://angular-maps.com. But we could not find suitable guide for implementing Azure Maps with Angular. Appreciate if you can kindly help on this matter.

Comment: Any JavaScript is Angular compatible, if there is not an Angular specific library you can still use any old JavaScript library with your Angular components.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. We'll look into the options available

Answer (score 1):

To add to Adrian's comment. Since you are looking to use Azure Maps in Angular, you might also be interested in the NPM package for Azure Maps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-maps-control If provides a copy of the source code and the typescript definitions. You can then either host the source code yourself and use it with things like require.js, or add a standard script tag to the hosted CDN version of Azure Maps.